# How to perform element-wise Boolean operations on NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, boolean-operations

For example, I would like to create a mask that masks elements with value between 40 and 60:

```
foo = np.asanyarray(range(100))
mask = (foo < 40).__or__(foo > 60)
```

Which just looks ugly. I can't write

```
(foo < 40) or (foo > 60)
```

because I end up with:

```
  ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
  ----> 1 (foo < 40) or (foo > 60)
  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a canonical way of doing element-wise Boolean operations on NumPy arrays with good looking code?

Comment: I'm not really convinced this is a duplicate. The other question is primarily about pandas.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Try this:

```
mask = (foo < 40) | (foo > 60)
```

Note: the `__or__` method in an object overloads the bitwise or operator (`|`), not the Boolean `or` operator.

Comment: it doesn't work: TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Don't forget to properly bracket your expressions

Comment: Hmm...why are the parentheses required?

Comment: @flow2k The reason is that bitwise or has higher precedence than the comparison operators (that doesn't happen with the boolean or). For more information, please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: @jcollado Thanks. It appears `|` is overloaded by NumPy to work with boolean NumPy arrays (since it doesn't act a strict "bitwise" operator anymore). Strangely, I was not able to find this documented in NumPy's documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and Or is it? What I'm trying to get at is...is it "officially" supported syntax?

Comment: @flow2k I think the documentation that you were looking for is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html): <<This ufunc implements the C/Python operator `|`>>.

Comment: @jcollado Great! Looks like `|` not only works element-wise, it will operate *bitwise* on those elements - which makes a difference for integer arrays, but not boolean arrays, in comparison to `np.logical_or(.)`. I like the `|` syntax more, but the requirement of parentheses in Python (a source of hard-to-find bugs) still makes me a little envious of MATLAB users...

Comment: Please be very cautions with this syntax in larger data sets... try the other solution below with `np.any` / `np.all` to avoid hard-to trace bugs in corner cases.

Answer (score 30):

You can use the [NumPy logical operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.logic.html). In your example:

```
np.logical_or(foo < 40, foo > 60)
```

Answer (score 26):

If you have comparisons within only Booleans, as in your example, you can use the bitwise OR operator `|` as suggested by Jcollado.  But beware, this can give you strange results if you ever use non-Booleans, such as `mask = (foo < 40) | override`. Only as long as `override` guaranteed to be either False, True, 1, or 0, are you fine.

More general is the use of NumPy's comparison set operators, `np.any` and `np.all`. This snippet returns all values between 35 and 45 which are less than 40 or not a multiple of 3:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.arange(35, 46)
mask = np.any([(foo < 40), (foo % 3)], axis=0)
print foo[mask]
OUTPUT: array([35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44])
```

It is not as nice as with `|`, but nicer than the code in your question.

Comment: It's  a good idea to use `np.any` and `np.all` specifically.

Comment: If you are thinking about other solutions, do not. It will save you a lot of misery!

Comment: Note that with `np.any` / `np.all` commas are sufficient to separate array conditions (no parentheses `()` required inside the brackets `[]` ), and you can have more than two conditions (evaluated element-wise as long as `axis=0` is set), provided they are of the same type (e.g. all conjunctions or all alternatives, but not a mix of conjunctions and alternatives)

Answer (score 9):

Note that you can use `~` for elementwise negation.

```
arr = np.array([False, True])
~arr

OUTPUT: array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Also `&` does elementwise *and*

```
arr_1 = np.array([False, False, True, True])
arr_2 = np.array([False, True, False, True])

arr_1 & arr_2

OUTPUT:   array([False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

These also work with *Pandas* Series

```
ser_1 = pd.Series([False, False, True, True])
ser_2 = pd.Series([False, True, False, True])

ser_1 & ser_2

OUTPUT:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: According to the numpy documentation, it seems like `&` does [_bitwise_ and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html#numpy.bitwise_and), not elementwise.

Comment: "The & operator can be used as a shorthand for np.logical_and on boolean ndarrays." https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and