# Element-wise logical OR in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-logic, logical-operators, boolean-operations

I am aware that AND corresponds to `&` and NOT, `~`. What is the element-wise logical OR operator? I know "or" itself is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The corresponding operator is `|`:

```
 df[(df < 3) | (df == 5)]
```

would elementwise check if value is less than 3 or equal to 5.

---

If you need a function to do this, we have [**`np.logical_or`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html). For two conditions, you can use

```
df[np.logical_or(df<3, df==5)]
```

Or, for multiple conditions use the `logical_or.reduce`,

```
df[np.logical_or.reduce([df<3, df==5])]
```

Since the conditions are specified as individual arguments, **parentheses grouping is not needed.**

More information on logical operations with pandas can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/4909087).

Comment: The round brackets *are* important

Comment: `|` and `np.logical_or` behave differently in the presence of NaNs. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37131462/2596586

Comment: Just a comment: `or` is not working here. Only `|` works.

Answer (score 12):

To take the element-wise logical OR of two Series `a` and `b` just do

```
a | b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you operate on the columns of a single dataframe, `eval` and `query` are options where `or` works element-wise. You don't need to worry about parenthesis either because comparison operators have higher precedence than boolean/bitwise operators. For example, the following `query` call returns rows where column A values are >1 and column B values are > 2.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,0], 'B': [0,1,2]})

df.query('A > 1 or B > 2')       # == df[(df['A']>1) | (df['B']>2)]
#    A  B
# 1  2  1
```

or with `eval` you can return a boolean Series (again `or` works just fine as element-wise operator).

```py
df.eval('A > 1 or B > 2')
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2    False
# dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Example with Series
s1 = pd.Series([True, False, True])
s2 = pd.Series([False, True, True])

result = s1 | s2

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

**# Example with DataFrames**

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True], 'B': [False, True, False]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [False, True, True], 'B': [True, False, True]})

result = df1 | df2

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
       A      B
0   True   True
1   True   True
2   True   True
```

the | operator or the or keyword is used to perform element-wise logical OR between corresponding elements in the Series or DataFrames. The resulting Series or DataFrame will have True where at least one of the corresponding elements in the input Series or DataFrames is True.