# How to compare four columns of pandas dataframe at a time?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have one dataframe.

**Dataframe :**

```
   Symbol1   BB Symbol2 CC 
0         ABC    1  ABC       1
1         PQR    1  PQR       1
2         CPC    2  CPC       0
3         CPC    2  CPC       1
4         CPC    2  CPC       2
```

I want to compare `Symbol1` with `Symbol2` and `BB` with `CC`, if they are same then I want that rows only other rows must be removed from the dataframe.

**Expected Result :**

```
Symbol1   BB Symbol2 CC 
0         ABC    1  ABC       1
1         PQR    1  PQR       1
2         CPC    2  CPC       2
```

If comparison between two rows then I'm using :

```
df = df[df['BB'] == '2'].copy()
```

It will work fine.

```
df = df[df['BB'] == df['offset'] and df['Symbol1'] == df['Symbol2']].copy()
```

It is giving me error.

**Error :**

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How I can compare and get expected result?

Comment: Please show your error, but you should use `&` (with parenthesis) instead of `and`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and compare with `&` instead [`and`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415990/2901002):

```
print ((df.Symbol1 == df.Symbol2) & (df.BB == df.CC))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

print (df[(df.Symbol1 == df.Symbol2) & (df.BB == df.CC)])
  Symbol1  BB Symbol2  CC
0     ABC   1     ABC   1
1     PQR   1     PQR   1
4     CPC   2     CPC   2
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that about boolean indexing with &.

Comment: If my or another answer was helpful, don't forget it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way, which is bit nicer, but it's also bit slower:

```
In [65]: df.query('Symbol1 == Symbol2 and BB == CC')
Out[65]:
  Symbol1  BB Symbol2  CC
0     ABC   1     ABC   1
1     PQR   1     PQR   1
4     CPC   2     CPC   2
```