# Pandas boolean operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ref   check        result
1     age          true
1     gender       false
1     address      false
1     nationality  true
```

I'm trying to create a new column of 1's and 0's if the following condition is satisfied.

```
if age == 'true' & (gender == 'false' or address == 'false') & nationality == 'true', then 1 else 0.
```

This is the code that I have

```
df['test']= ((df['check']=='age' & df['result']=='true') & ((df['check']=='gender' / df['check']=='address') & df['result']=='false') & (df['check']=='nationality' & df['result']=='true')).astype('int')
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Python doesn't have an `&` boolean operator. You need to use the word `and`.

Comment: @EliSadoff It does. Bitwise and

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I corrected my comment to say boolean `&` the second before you posted that. Nice catch though!

Comment: Yep, I can do &'s but not or's. That's the problem.

Comment: `|` is the bitwise or.

Comment: You either want to use `|` with `&` or `or` with `and`. You don't want to mix and match as they're not the same thing.

Comment: It's unclear what the desired output should be as it looks like your rows somehow have an interdependency on each other, is this because they have the same `ref` value?

Comment: I guess you want `|` instead of `/` for "or".

Comment: Oh thanks! I feel stupid now. It's the `|` that I was looking for.
@EdChum Yeah so, if the `age` = `true` and either the `gender` or `address` = 'false' and `nationality' = 'true', then the result = 1 (for each unique value in df['ref']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for in place of the `/` is `|`. But I would generally not advise to use bitwise operators for conditionals. They'll work when the operands evaluate to `True` and `False` but would give wrong results when the conditionals are say ints or you need to short circuit.

On another note the precedence of `&` and `|` is higher than that of `==` so that expression won't do what you actually expect e.g:

```
df['check']=='age' & df['result']=='true'
```

is evaluated as:

```
df['check']== ('age' & df['result']) =='true'
```

You can wrap the operators in parenthesis to change the order of evaluation:

```
(df['check']== 'age') & (df['result']) =='true')
```

**Update** @kennytm

You don't need `and` or `or` in this case just use the parens appropriately.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know about that. I'll stick to and and or.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you *can't* use `and` here, since `&`, `|`, `~` have special meanings in Pandas (numpy). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas

Comment: @kennytm I actually forgot that numpy feature. Thanks for the pointer