# Drop observations in Pandas when all values equal multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have several datasets where I need to discard observations if all the values in a subset of columns are equal to 0 or N (depending on the column).  For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[0,0,1,2,0], 'two':[0,0,0,0,0], 'three':['N','Y','N','Y','N']})
drop_subset = ['one', 'three']

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   one three  two
0    0     N    0
1    0     Y    0
2    1     N    0
3    2     Y    0
4    0     N    0
```

I need to look at just columns `one` and `three`, then drop rows 0 and 4 only.  If it were just a single value rather than two or more, I would use this:

```
df[~(df[drop_subset] == 0).all(axis=1)]
```

And it would work fine.  But when I try to expand it out:

```
df[~(df[drop_subset] == 0 or df[drop_subset] == 'N').all(axis=1)]
```

I get the dreaded:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I originally thought to treat each of the inner conditions using the `any` or `all` operators... except that the logic doesn't work that way.  I don't need to know if any or all of the values are 0, or separately whether any or all of the values are N.  I need to know if *all* of the values are N or 0.  That is, there's nothing I can do with this:

```
In [71]: (df[drop_subset] == 0)
Out[71]:
     one  three
0   True  False
1   True  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4   True  False
```

without simultaneously testing for the 'N' value also.  And while it seems obvious on this small dataframe that I could test column `one` for 0 and column `three` for 'N' separately, in reality my `drop_subset` includes almost 100 columns, which differ across three different datasets, and without manually encoding all of them I don't know which columns would have 0 and which would have 'N'.  **All I know for certain is that if an observation has *all* 0 or 'N' across this subset then I need to drop it.**

My last resort is using apply with a lambda, but it would be painfully slow due to the size of the data.  Plus I feel like there must be a vectorized way to express this logic in Panadas, and that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use [DataFrame.isin()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) method:

```
In [68]: df[df[drop_subset].isin([0,'N']).all(1)]
Out[68]:
   one three  two
0    0     N    0
4    0     N    0

In [69]: df[~df[drop_subset].isin([0,'N']).all(1)]
Out[69]:
   one three  two
1    0     Y    0
2    1     N    0
3    2     Y    0
```

Comment: That's the one, thanks.  Although I have to say it's disappointing this can't be done with boolean operators.

Comment: Well, your suggestion for `isin` is very clean and fast, so there's no real need.  It just seems like something that *should* work within Pandas, which isn't really a problem you run into a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think Max nailed it in his answer, `isin` is naturally what you should use.

In fact, it is what you **must** use, since `df[drop_subset] == 'N'`won't work anyways, you'll get:

```
TypeError: Could not compare ['N'] with block values
```

You need isin() for this job.

I specifically wanted to point out that the error you got, "truth value of [DataFrame/Series] is ambiguous" comes from the fact that you should always use `&` instead of `and`, and `|` instead of `or`.

The binary operators `&` and `|` will return an element-wise comparison and will therefore return an array.
The `and` and `or` try to cast it to a single boolean value for comparison, which doesn't exist.

Read more here: [Logic operator for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas).

Comment: Yeah, I actually used the pipe first, but ran into the block values error.  But apparently that's an unrelated issue.