# Query pandas data frame with `or`b boolean?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a simple pandas data frame.

```
import pandas as pd    
x = [5, 10, 20, 30, 5, 10, 20, 30, 5, 10, 20, 30]
y = [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400, 400, 500, 500, 600, 600]
users =['mark', 'mark', 'mark', 'rachel', 'rachel', 'rachel', 'jeff', 'jeff', 'jeff', 'lauren', 'lauren', 'lauren']

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, y=y, users=users)
```

I want to keep certain rows of the data frame. Let's say all "rachels" and "jeffs". I tried `df.query`:

```
df=df.query('users=="rachel"' or 'users=="jeff"')
```

The result is a data frame only with `users=="rachel"`. Is there a way to combine queries?

Comment: `df.query('(users=="rachel") or (users=="jeff")')` or even `df.query('users=="rachel" or users=="jeff"')` will do the trick. Tested with `pandas==1.2.4`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The standard way would be to use the bitwise or operator `|`. For a clear explanation of why, I'd suggest checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas). You also need to use parentheses around each condition due to Python's order of evaluation.

```
df[(df.users == 'rachel') | (df.users == 'jeff')]
    users   x    y
3  rachel  30  200
4  rachel   5  300
5  rachel  10  300
6    jeff  20  400
7    jeff  30  400
8    jeff   5  500
```

Using query, you can still just use the or operator:

```
df.query("users=='rachel' | users=='jeff'")
    users   x    y
3  rachel  30  200
4  rachel   5  300
5  rachel  10  300
6    jeff  20  400
7    jeff  30  400
8    jeff   5  500
```

Comment: No worries. @EdChum's comment is also a simple solution.

Comment: How would you create logic to show only results where name is either rachel or jeff, AND hometown was Chicago?  So all rachels from Chicago, and all jeffs from Chicago, but not steves from chicago, or rachels from Atlanta.  Could you use "users =='rachel' | users=='jeff' & hometown=='chicago'", or would the AND only apply to the jeffs, and you need to include the " & hometown=='Chicago'" to both sides of the OR?

Comment: @Korzak I don't know if you need an answer at this time, but I assume, using () does the trick. So the statement would be "(user=='rachel' | user=='jeff') & hometown == chicago". With this the inner statement will filter the names and the outer statement only shows rachels and jeffs from chicago.

Answer (score -1):

another way is :

```
df=df.query('users=="rachel"').append(df.query('users=="jeff"'))
```