# Subset pandas dataframe using values from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a pandas dataframe based on values of two columns. I tried this code:
`df[df['gold']>0, df['silver']>0, df['bronze']>0]` but this didn't work.

I  also tried:
`df[(df['gold']>0 and df['silver']>0)`. This didn't work too. I got an error saying:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What would you suggest?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas#21415990

Answer (score 15):

I will answer my own question, hoping it will help someone. I tried this and it worked.
`df[(df['gold']>0) & (df['silver']>0)]`

Note that I have used `&` instead of `and` and I have used brackets to separate the different conditions.