# Python : How to use if elif for rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe and i want to add a columns using if elif condition on the rows of the table. I am using if elif statement but that is not working.
Can we not use the conditional statememt for a data frame?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['a', 'a', 'q', 'a'],
              'c2': ['b', 'e', 'b', 'f'],
               'c3': ['c', 'f', 'c', 'd']})

if [(df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2']=='b')]:
    df['q']= df['c1'] + '+' + df['c2']
elif (df['c1']=='a' & df['c2']=='e'):
    df['q'] = df['c1'] + '*' + df['c2']
else:
    df['q'] = df['c1'] + '-' + df['c2']
```

The new column 'q' has contents: 'a+b', 'a+e', 'q+b', 'a+f'

While i want it as:
     'a+b', 'a*e', 'q-b', 'a-f'

Comment: Instead of using '&' operator in your conditions use 'and'.

Comment: @AnkurSharma see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415990/2689986

Comment: @sky_bird what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks

Comment: 'and' doesn't work. It is showing an error.  "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Follow the link stated in Ashish's comment.

Comment: You might also want to consider creating a function to assign the value of `df['q']` then apply that function to each row.  That will make the implementation easier to read rather than having this long if-else statement of column references.

Comment: can you add the output you''re expecting?

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak, added the detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) what is better readability form of multiple nested `np.where`:

```
m1 = (df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2']=='b')
m2 = (df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2']=='e')

a1 = df['c1'] + '+' + df['c2']
a2 = df['c1'] + '*' + df['c2']
a3 = df['c1'] + '-' + df['c2']

df['q'] = np.select([m1, m2], [a1, a2], default=a3)
print (df)

  c1 c2 c3    q
0  a  b  c  a+b
1  a  e  f  a*e
2  q  b  c  q-b
3  a  f  d  a-f
```

Comment: It helped me..thanx!!

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized version of if statements is `np.where`. I assigned the conditions and the possible outcomes to variables to improve readability because with nested `np.where`s it may become hard to follow.

```
cond1 = (df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2']=='b')
cond2 = (df['c1']=='a') & (df['c2']=='e')

case1 = df['c1'] + '+' + df['c2']
case2 = df['c1'] + '*' + df['c2']
case3 = df['c1'] + '-' + df['c2']

df['q'] = np.where(cond1, case1, np.where(cond2, case2, case3))

df
Out: 
  c1 c2 c3    q
0  a  b  c  a+b
1  a  e  f  a*e
2  q  b  c  q-b
3  a  f  d  a-f
```