# Specifying conditional expressions with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'd like to figure out how I can create a column in my dataframe based on a multiple check condition.

When I use a single conditional check this seems to work fine.

```
df['1/1/2017'] = np.where(df["Term 1 Start Date"] <= '1/1/2017'), 'True', 'False')
```

However when I introduce a second option to check upon this fails telling me that `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.`

```
df['1/1/2017'] = np.where(
    (df["Term 1 Start Date"] <= '1/1/2017' and df["Term 1 End Date"] > '1/1/2017'), 'True', 'False')
```

It should be noted that not all lines are filled in. The dates contain dates as you would expect. 
What can I do to have this new column populate based on two criteria?

current dataframe

Desired result

Term 1 Start Date | 1/1/2017
blank   | blank
6/12/2016 | True
5/1/2016  | True
2/1/2017  | False
4/1/2017  | False

Comment: check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the bitwise operator `&` instead of `and`. You'll also need extra sets of parentheses to handle precedence.

```
df['1/1/2017'] = np.where(((df["Term 1 Start Date"] <= '1/1/2017')\ 
                           & (df["Term 1 End Date"] > '1/1/2017'),\
                     'True', 'False'))
```

Reason being, `and` doesn't play nice with dataframes, but the bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `~` are all overloaded for use in conditionals.