# Invalid syntax in python function to create new column based o n conditions in two other ones

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, syntax

I keep getting the error message `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and I would like to know (1) why this is and (2) how to fix my function so that it does what I want.

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
d = {'Relationship': ['Male', 'Female','Spouse','Spouse','Male','Spouse','Male','Male','Male','Spouse','Female'], 'Sex': ['Male', 'Female','Female','Male','Male','Female','Male','Male','Male','Female','Female']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

Relationship    Sex
Male            Male
Female          Female
Spouse          Female
Spouse          Male
Male            Male
Spouse          Female
Male            Male
Male            Male
Male            Male
Spouse          Female
Female          Female
```

And what I want is for each instance of `Spouse` to be filled in with the opposite sex listed in `df['Sex']`. So the df should look like this:

```
df

Relationship    Sex
Male            Male
Female          Female
Male            Female
Female          Male
Male            Male
Male            Female
Male            Male
Male            Male
Male            Male
Male            Female
Female          Female
```

This is the function I've written:

```
def typex(column):
    if column['Relationship']!='Spouse' & column['Sex']! ='Female':
        return 'Male'
    elif column['Relationship']!='Spouse' & column['Sex']! ='Male':
        return 'Female'

df.loc[:,'Relationship'] = df.apply(typex, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for vectorized solution:

```
m1 = (df['Relationship']!='Spouse') & (df['Sex']!='Female')
m2 = (df['Relationship']!='Spouse') & (df['Sex']!='Male')

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['Male','Female'], default='not matched')
```

But if want use your code change `&` to `and` [because working with scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21415990):

```
def typex(column):
    if (column['Relationship']=='Spouse') and (column['Sex']=='Female'):
        return 'Male'
    elif (column['Relationship']=='Spouse') and (column['Sex']='Male'):
        return 'Female'

df['new'] = df.apply(typex, axis=1)
```

Comment: I get the error message `TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')` when I use your second solution. Any ideas why?

Comment: @JAG2024 - Maybe `()` are necesarry like in first solution.

Comment: I edited your function to one that worked for me. Perhaps there's a more elegant way...