# Pandas dataframe: Find location where value changes from x to y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the points in a dataframe where the data hits a max value, holds it for a time, then drops down again (See image below).

[image]

I am attempting to find the index's where the value first hits the max and where it first leaves it. I've attempted it in the following way.

```
ent = data.loc[data['ESC_Command'] == 1600 and data['ESC_Command'].shift() < 1600]
lve = data.loc[data['ESC_Command'] == 1600 and data['ESC_Command'].shift(-1) < 1600]
```

But when I run this I get the following error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I run either the 'equals to 1600' or the '< 1600' with the shift I get the expected boolean list but adding a logical statement gets me that error. Don't suppose anyone can shed some light onto what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `and` with `&`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logic-operator-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the bitwise operator (`&`) to combine your masks (`(data['ESC_Command'] == 1600) & (data['ESC_Command'].shift() < 1600)`).

`and` is the logical operator and is unable to compare series, hence the `ValueError`.

---

Also, you can use `data['ESC_Command'].max()` to dynamically find the maximum value in the column.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I was guessing I was just doing something dumb like that! I didn't think I could use the .max() operator as the series hits that max value multiple times and I needed to identify each one.