# how to cap pandas column with mean values with some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 ID      Quantity       Rate       Product
 1       10             70         MS
 2       10             70         MS
 3       100            70         MS
 4       10             100        MS
 5       700            65         HS
 6       1100           65         HS
 7       700            100        HS
```

I want to cap values with mean values in `Quantity and Rate` For `MS` if `Quantity is greater than 100 and Rate is greater than 99` then it should be replaced by mean and For `HS` if `Quantity is greater than 1000 and Rate is greater than 99` then it should be replaced by mean.

I am using following way

```
 mean_MS = df['Quantity'][(df['Product'] == 'MS') and (df['Quantity'] < 100)].mean()
```

But it does not work.

My desired dataframe would be

```
 ID      Quantity       Rate       Product
 1       10             70         MS
 2       10             70         MS
 3       10             70         MS
 4       10             70         MS
 5       700            65         HS
 6       700            65         HS
 7       700            65         HS
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/4909087)

Comment: `Quantity` should be greater than or less than 100  for `MS`?

Comment: Yes this is not correct

Comment: @neil - Is my proposed solution working for you? feel free if you still stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

one way to solve this,

```
m1=df['Product']=='MS'
m2=(df['Quantity']>=100)|(df['Rate']>99)
df.loc[m1&m2,'Quantity']=df[m1&(df['Quantity']<100)]['Quantity'].mean()
df.loc[m1&m2,'Rate']=df[m1&(df['Rate']<99)]['Rate'].mean()

m3=df['Product']=='HS'
m4=(df['Quantity']>=1000)|(df['Rate']>99)
df.loc[m3&m4,'Quantity']=df[m3&(df['Quantity']<1000)]['Quantity'].mean()
df.loc[m3&m4,'Rate']=df[m3&(df['Rate']<99)]['Rate'].mean()
```

O/P:

```
   ID  Quantity  Rate Product
0   1      10.0  70.0      MS
1   2      10.0  70.0      MS
2   3      10.0  70.0      MS
3   4      10.0  70.0      MS
4   5     700.0  65.0      HS
5   6     700.0  65.0      HS
6   7     700.0  65.0      HS
```

Explanation:

1. divide your problem into two sub models one is `MS` and another one is `HS` for both contains same logic but differs in quantity value.
2. first you have to change value only for MS so flag that in m1 then if Quantity is greater than or equal to 100 or Rate is greater than 99 replace the mean value from the df where df contains required `MS` row and clearing out the values where our condition exceeds.
3. repeat the same logic for Rate.
4. repeat step 2 and 3 for `HS` too where Quantity condition modified from 100 to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC , you can also try the below:

```
val1= df.loc[df.Product.eq('MS'),['Quantity','Rate']].mode().values 
#array([[10, 70]], dtype=int64)
val2= df.loc[df.Product.eq('HS'),['Quantity','Rate']].mode().values
#array([[700,  65]], dtype=int64)

df.loc[df.Product.eq('MS')&df.Quantity.ge(100)|df.Product.eq('MS')&df.Rate.gt(99),['Quantity','Rate']] = val1

df.loc[df.Product.eq('HS')&df.Quantity.ge(1000)|df.Product.eq('HS')&df.Rate.gt(99),['Quantity','Rate']] = val2
print(df)

   ID  Quantity  Rate Product
0   1        10    70      MS
1   2        10    70      MS
2   3        10    70      MS
3   4        10    70      MS
4   5       700    65      HS
5   6       700    65      HS
6   7       700    65      HS
```