# What happened to python's ~ when working with boolean?

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

In a pandas DataFrame, I have a series of boolean values. In order to filter to rows where the boolean is True, I can use: `df[df.column_x]`

I thought in order to filter to only rows where the column is False, I could use: `df[~df.column_x]`. I feel like I have done this before, and have seen it as the accepted answer.

However, this fails because `~df.column_x` converts the values to integers. See below.

````
import pandas as pd . # version 0.24.2

a = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'])
b = pd.Series([True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

c = pd.DataFrame(data=[a, b]).T
c.columns = ['Classification', 'Boolean']```

print(~c.Boolean)

0    -2
1    -2
2    -2
3    -2
4    -2
5    -1
6    -1
7    -1
8    -1
9    -1
Name: Boolean, dtype: object

print(~b)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool
````

Basically, I can use `c[~b]`, but not `c[~c.Boolean]`

Am I just dreaming that this use to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas  The very last part of the lowest rated comment highlights this problem as well

Comment: I think since a boolean is pretty small, the Pythons tend to get entangled with one another if they try to work on the boolean together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ah , since you created the `c` by using `DataFrame` constructor , then `T`,

1st let us look at what we have before `T`:

```
pd.DataFrame([a, b])
Out[610]: 
      0     1     2     3     4      5      6      7      8      9
0     a     a     a     a     b      a      b      b      b      b
1  True  True  True  True  True  False  False  False  False  False
```

So `pandas` will make each columns ***only have one*** `dtype`, if not it will convert to `object` .

*After `T` what data type we have for each columns*

The `dtypes` in your `c` :

```
c.dtypes
Out[608]: 
Classification    object
Boolean           object
```

`Boolean` `columns` became `object` type , that is why you get unexpected output for `~c.Boolean`

---

How to fix it ? ---`concat`

```
c=pd.concat([a,b],1)
c.columns = ['Classification', 'Boolean']
~c.Boolean
Out[616]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: Boolean, dtype: bool
```

Comment: In my real dataset, the column comes as an object. Based off of WenYoBen's response, I should make my column a boolean dtype.


`df.column_x = df.column_x_.astype(bool);
df[~df.column_x]`