# what is wrong with this pandas expression

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, the answer may be obvious.

I have 3 series of the same length: a, b, c

```
a[b > c] = 0
```

works, but:

```
a[math.fabs(b) > c] = 0
```

doesn't work, and

```
a[(b > c or b < -c)] = 0
```

doesn't work either.

How can I implement that logic?

Comment: `a[(b>c) | (b<-c)]` or `a[b.abs().gt(c)]`? Make sure that `a,b,c` are not just equal length, they should have same indexing as well.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] for your issue so that we can provide more specific help

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Do you get an error?  Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: On your third example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas).

Comment: @JohnGordon, sorry I should have written the error: <class 'tuple'>: (<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'), None)

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that in the first expression the expression you use is vectorized while in the other one it is not.

- In the first expression, the `<` operation between two series returns a series as well
- In the second expression, `math.fabs` is supposed to be applied elements by elements and not to an array/series of elements (try the numpy version instead is it exists).
- In the third expression, the `or` operation is not vectorized and you should use `|` instead.