# how to join 2 queries with && in pandas?

Tags: pandas

the dataframe has age column. I want to select only those btw 0 and 100.

usually I do this, first select < 100 then select > 0:

```
   df_clients = df_clients[df_clients['age'] <100) 
   df_clients = df_clients[df_clients['age']> 0]
```

The other way is this:

```
df_clients = df_clients[(df_clients['age'] <100) & (df_clients['age']> 0)]
```

How to do this with 'and' or '&&'  - double && ?

Comment: @ayhan, i want to find alternative way of doing this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas for explanation why you can't use `and` or `&&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.logical_and` with `reduce`:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    df_clients['age'] > 0,
    df_clients['age'] < 100, 
]

mask = np.logical_and.reduce(conditions)

df_clients = df_clients[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df_clients = df_clients[df_clients['age'] < 100][df_clients['age'] > 0]
```