# Why do i get this error when I try to perform some logical operation on dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my DataFrame:
[image: DataFrame]

```
data.where(data["Gender"] == "Male") and data.where(data["Age"] == 19)
```

I'm trying to print matching values but i get this error. Explain the output.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 data.where(data["Gender"] == "Male") and data.where(data["Age"] == 19)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1553             "The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1554             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().".format(
-> 1555                 self.__class__.__name__
   1556             )
   1557         )

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. Where is the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check both conditions at once:

```py
data.where(data["Gender"] == "Male" and data["Age"] == 19)
```

Comment: Even this gives the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error as you're comparing with `and` when you should be using `&`. You should also separate with brackets. Try the following.

```
data[(data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19)]
```

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas) for more details.

## Example

For some dummy data

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Gender' : np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], 20),
                          'Age' : np.random.randint(30, size=20)})
```

using the code above outputs

```
    Gender  Age
12    Male   19
14    Male   19
```

If you want to return all values, including null values, use:

```
data.where((data["Gender"] == "Male") & (data["Age"] == 19))
```

Comment: consider i didn't have Purchased column and I'm trying to add it by matching those independent attributes using if condition. Now i tried and again I'm getting the same error. ``` data["Purchased"] = 
if data[(data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19) & (data['EstimatedSalary'] == 19000)]:
    Purchased = 0
    data['Purchased'] = Purchased ```

Comment: Try `data["Purchased"] = (data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19) & (data['EstimatedSalary'] == 19000)` This will return a boolean, which can be converted to integers afterwards. If you want `True = 1` and `False = 0`, you can use `astype(int)` after this expression. So  `data["Purchased"] = (data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19) & (data['EstimatedSalary'] == 19000).astype(int)`

Comment: I meant `data["Purchased"] = ((data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19) & (data['EstimatedSalary'] == 19000)).astype(int)`. This includes the extra closing brackets

Comment: @saicharanpogul Read the Pandas docs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the operands for your *and*:

```
data.where(data["Gender"] == "Male")
    and
data.where(data["Age"] == 19)
```

`where` returns a new data frame.  You're trying to perform a logical `and` between two data frames.  What is this supposed to mean ???  :-)

As others have already pointed out, what *you* want is to filter rows that satisfy both conditions.  Thus, you need to apply `and` to the conditions, not to the resulting filtered data frames:

```
data.where(
    data["Gender"] == "Male"
        &
    data["Age"] == 19
)
```

This properly performs `and` on a pair of Boolean values.

Comment: For me, this still raises the same error. However, using `data.where((data["Gender"] == "Male") & (data["Age"] == 19))` doesn't. At least it does in the example code I made in my response (which i think is representative of the actual data)

Comment: Right; I forgot to edit the operator, as you pointed out earlier.

Comment: data.where((data["Gender"] == "Male") & (data["Age"] == 19)) this gives with nan values.

Comment: It also needs brackets around each condition, otherwise it raises a further TypeError

Comment: @Josmoor98 data.where((data["Gender"] == "Male") & (data["Age"] == 19)) and data[(data['Gender'] == 'Male') & (data['Age'] == 19)] what difference does the brackets and parentheses have?