# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous while using lambda with loc

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, pandas-loc

```
Df.loc[lambda Df: Df['score'] > 15 and Df['score'] < 20]
```

I am getting the mentioned error while using the above-mentioned code. Thanks in advance
**Error** : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is the lack of parenthesis around the expressions.

There are two other issues in your code:

- Use '&' instead of 'and' when working with Series.
- No need to use lambda.

Here's a piece of code that would work:

```
df.loc[(df['score'] > 15) & (df['score'] < 20)]
```