# When to use .loc and when not to use (Pandas Dataframe)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Can someone please help me understand, while subsetting a dataframe, we generally do

```
df.loc[df['col_1']==0]
```

But when I have to subset based on two column values or multiple criteria, we do this instead

```
df[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0)]
```

Why is ***.loc*** not used in 2nd criteria?

Also, why can't we use ***and*** in the second code, i.e.

```
df[(df['col_1']==0) and (df['col_2']>0)] ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is .loc not used in 2nd criteria?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({

         'col_1':[0,3,0,7,1,0],
         'col_2':[0,3,6,9,2,4],
         'col3':list('aaabbb')
})
```

No, you are wrong, it working in both.

```
print (df.loc[df['col_1']==0])
   col_1  col_2 col3
0      0      0    a
2      0      6    a
5      0      4    b

print (df.loc[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0)])
   col_1  col_2 col3
2      0      6    a
5      0      4    b
```

---

```
print (df[df['col_1']==0])
   col_1  col_2 col3
0      0      0    a
2      0      6    a
5      0      4    b

print (df[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0)])
   col_1  col_2 col3
2      0      6    a
5      0      4    b
```

Reason for using is if need also filter columns names, e.g. `col_1`:

```
print (df.loc[df['col_1']==0, 'col_2'])
0    0
2    6
5    4
Name: col_2, dtype: int64


print (df.loc[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0), 'col_2'])
2    6
5    4
Name: col_2, dtype: int64
```

If need filter 2 or more columns use list, e.g for `col_1,col3` use:

```
print (df.loc[df['col_1']==0, ['col_1','col3']])
   col_1 col3
0      0    a
2      0    a
5      0    b

print (df.loc[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0), ['col_1','col3']])
   col_1 col3
2      0    a
5      0    b
```

If omit `loc` it failed:

```
df[df['col_1']==0, 'col_1']
df[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0), 'col_1']
```

> TypeError

---

Also, why can't we use **and** in the second code, i.e.

```
df[(df['col_1']==0) and (df['col_2']>0)]
```

becasue `and` is for processing by scalars, in pandas are used `&` for bitwise `AND` - `&`.  More info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas).

Comment: If I do this `df.loc[(df['col_1']==0) & (df['col_2']>0)]`
I'm getting invalid syntax error

Comment: @lightyagami96 - For me working nice, added to answer.

Comment: @lightyagami96 - What is your pandas version?

Comment: my version is 1.1.1

Comment: @lightyagami96 - Tested in `pandas 1.1.1`, not idea :(

Comment: actually it worked. I can't understand why, but last time it was throwing error.

Thanks for trying this out and helping me.