# How to combine two columns in a df as a condition in np.where to check if nan in calculating new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to check if either column contains a nan and if so the value in my new column to be "na" else 1.

I was able to get my code to work when checking a single column using .isnull() but I am unsure how to combine two. I tried using or as seen below. But it did not work. I know I can make the code a bit messy by testing one condition and then checking the next and from that producing the outcome I want but was hoping to make the code a bit cleaner by using some sort of any, or etc function instead but I do not know how to do that.

```
temp_df["xl"] = np.where(temp_df["x"].isnull() or temp_df["y"].isnull(), "na",1)
```

Comment: Use `temp_df["x"].isnull()|temp_df["y"].isnull()`.

Comment: Can I Just ask what does the | do exactly does it just mean or? I tried to google but nothing came up for it

Comment: It is bitwise operator `or`. See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for the official pandas doc on boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `any` more detail explain the situation you have [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

```
temp_df["xl"] = np.where(temp_df[['x','y']].isnull().any(1), "na",1)
```