# How to get a new numpy array based on conditions of two other numpy arrays using only numpy operations?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have np.array of `a = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]` and `b = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]`

I want a new matrix c such that if `a[i] = 0` and `b[i] = 0` then `c[i] = True`

I've tried using `c = np.where(a == 0 & b==0)` but seems this won't work on two arrays.

Ultimately I want a count of '0's that are true in both cases and '1's that are true in both cases without using any loops and external libraries. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Your logic expression is nothing but c = NOT (a OR b). This means, you want `c[i] = True`, only if both `a[i]` and `b[i]` are zero. The OR can be achieved by adding the two arrays. We then convert the array into a boolean type and invert it.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

c = np.invert((a+b).astype('bool'))
```

If you then want to count the number of zeros you can simply perform

```py
n_zeros = np.sum(c)
```

**More general solution:**

If you want your array `c[i] = True` if `a[i] == a0 and b[i] == b0`, you can do:

```py
c = (a == a0) & (b == b0)
```

The conditions `a == a0` and `b == b0` return each a boolean array with the truth value of the condition for each individual array element. The bitwise operator `&` performs an element-wise logical AND. For more bitwise operators see https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators.

Comment: That's an interesting answer. But what if I want ```if a[i] = 0 and b[i] = 1``` then ```c[i] = True```? Would be nice to be able to use condition.

Comment: I added a more general solution, I hope that works for you. You cannot use logical operators on numpy arrays you would need bitwise operators, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/. So in this case instead of the multiplication you could use &.

Comment: Yes this is it! This is dot product right? But why does it work this way? Thanks.

Comment: No, the `*` is the element-wise multiplication of the two arrays in the brackets, which in turn are boolean arrays. If you multiply two booleans, the result is `True` if both are `True`, otherwise it's `False`. So this is equivalent to an logical AND.

Comment: I edited my answer, such that it uses bitwise operators instead of aritmethic operators, it should be clearer now.