# delete CSV rows with conditional in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have a csv file with the following:

```
storeNumber, sale1, sale2
1, 1, 1
2, 0, 0
3, 1, 0
4, 0, 1
...
25, 0, 0
26, 1, 0
27, 0, 1
28, 0,0
```

I need to delete rows with sale1 and sale2 that are equal to 0.

I have the following code setup:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', index_col=0)

df_new = df[df.sale1 != 0] and df[df.sale2 != 0]

print(df_new)
```

the code works if I will only delete one of each column that has 0 value.

```
df_new = df[df.sale1 != 0]
```

or

```
df_new = df[df.sale2 != 0]
```

However, when put the code above with the "and", I get an error that says:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what is the right code for deleting rows that have 0 value for both sale1 and sale2?

Comment: Make sure the code doesn't have a typo: in your example with the `and` you use `df.KC_2` on both sides of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

To operator you need to use to combine the two logical conditions is `&` instead of `and`. This is explained in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas). So, what you need is:

```
df_new = df[(df.sale1 != 0) & (df[df.sale2 != 0)]
```

Notice that both conditions must be in parentheses since `&` binds stronger than `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing this would be to keep only rows where any of the two columns is not equal to zero.

```
df.loc[df[['KC_1','KC_2']].ne(0).any(axis=1)]
```