# filter pandas df with list comprehension instead of multiple ampersands

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with the columns `dataset`, `inflation`, `cat`, `region`, and some other values.

I want to filter my df according to the values of a list (or tuple) where the list has the values of those columns that I want to select.

My filter list will look like

```
filterlist=['abc', 'real', 'food', 'central']
```

What I'm doing now is

```
DF.loc[(DF['dataset']==filterlist[0]) & (DF['inflation']==filterlist[1]) & (DF['cat']==filterlist[2]) & (DF['region']==filterlist[3])]
```

I'd like to do something more like this:

```
id_cols=['dataset', 'inflation', 'cat', 'region']
DF.loc[[DF[x]==y for x,y in zip(id_cols, filterlist)]]
```

I hacked this together which technically works but isn't very readable, just looks clunky, and has terrible `%%timeit` performance (1.18ms vs 654 µs)

```
DF.iloc[list(set.intersection(*[set(DF[DF[id_cols[x]]==filterlist[x]].index) for x in range(len(id_cols))])),:]
```

I also did

```
DF.query(' and '.join([f"{x} == '{y}'" for x,y in zip(id_cols, filterlist)]))
```

This has the benefit of being fairly readable but is even worse performance.
There's got to be a better way!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `np.logical_and.reduce`

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas)

I found that I can do:

```
DF[np.logical_and.reduce([DF[x]==y for x,y in zip(id_cols, filterlist)])]
```

The `%%timeit` on this one is just 470 µs which is even better than the parenthesis laden example.

Comment: I selected my answer as the logical_and.reduce is faster, at least for my use case, than the 2D comparison in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2D comparison:

```
cols = ['dataset', 'inflation', 'cat', 'region']

out = df[df[cols].eq(filterlist).all(1)]
```

output:

```
  dataset inflation   cat   region
0     abc      real  food  central
```

example input `df`:

```
  dataset inflation   cat   region
0     abc      real  food  central
1     abc         X  food  central
2     abc      real     X  central
```

intermediates:

```
df[cols].eq(filterlist)
   dataset  inflation    cat  region
0     True       True   True    True
1     True      False   True    True
2     True       True  False    True

df[cols].eq(filterlist).all(1)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```