# Python Pandas Question - 'and' and 'or' operators

Tags: python, pandas

So I got a strange question...

I'm basically trying to do some filtering on a dataframe, and I realized these 2 lines result in a error.

```
sel = data[(data["Fare"] == 50) and (data["Sex"].isin(["male"]))]
sel = data[(data["Fare"] == 50) or (data["Sex"].isin(["male"]))]
```

But when I use | and &, instead of 'and' and 'or', it WORKS:

```
sel = data[(data["Fare"] == 50) & (data["Sex"].isin(["male"]))]
sel = data[(data["Fare"] == 50) | (data["Sex"].isin(["male"]))]
```

So my question is, why does the 'and' and 'or' not work?

Why do only the symbols work instead?

Comment: because the operation must be vectorized and `and`/`or` do now allow it

Comment: does this post help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas