# Checking a column in a Pandas df does not contain certain text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to write a specific value to a column in a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) df depending on if another column does or does not contain certain text. I have 3 outputs in the destination columns: `Distributor`, `OEM` and `End User`.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Customer Records.xlsx")

#Checking for distributor pricing tag
df.loc[df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-Distributor-STD'), 'Customer Type'] = 'Distributor'
    
#Checking for OEM pricing tag
df.loc[df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-OEM-STD'),         'Customer Type'] = 'OEM'
```

Those lines of code work as intended.

The last thing I need is for every other string that contains **neither** of those phrases to print `"End User"` in the `'Customer Type'` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conds = [
    df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-Distributor-STD'),
    df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-OEM-STD')
]
choices = ['Distributor', 'OEM']

df['Customer Type'] = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices, default='End User')
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` means "or", and `~` flips the boolean, so `False -> True`.  You can combine these together:

```py
df.loc[~(df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-Distributor-STD')\
         | df['CustomerRoles'].str.contains('Discount-OEM-STD')),
       "Customer Type"] = "End User"
```

There is a very good explanation of the different logical operators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358361/18571565) by @cs95.