# Bitwise input verification with Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632033/how-to-perform-element-wise-boolean-operations-on-numpy-arrays) and understand that Numpy arrays cannot be used in boolean context. Let's say I want to perform an element-wise boolean check on the validity of inputs to a function. Can I realize this behavior while still using Numpy vectorization, and if so, how? (and if not, why?)

In the following example, I compute a value from two inputs while checking that both inputs are valid (both must be greater than 0)

```py
import math, numpy
def calculate(input_1, input_2):
    if input_1 < 0 or input_2 < 0:
        return 0
    return math.sqrt(input_1) + math.sqrt(input_2)
calculate_many = (lambda x: calculate(x, 20 - x))(np.arange(-20, 40))
```

By itself, this would not work with Numpy arrays because of `ValueError`. But, it is imperative that `math.sqrt` is never run on negative inputs because that would result in another error.

One solution using list comprehension is as follows:

```py
calculate_many = [calculate(x, 20 - x) for x in np.arange(-20, 40)]/=
```

However, this no longer uses vectorization and would be painfully slow if the size of the `arange` was increased drastically.
Is there a way to implement this `if` check while still using vectorization?

Comment: `math.sqrt` only works with scalars, so your `calculate`, even without the `if`, does not work with the whole array - ie. there's no "vectorization".  There is a `np.sqrt` that works with an whole array.  It accepts a `where` parameter to control which values are evaluated (use it with the `out` parameter).

Comment: What does it mean for optional `where` to be an array-like?
Does that mean I would write `np.sqrt(input_1, input_1 > 0)` if I wanted to square root all positive numbers in `input_1` and leave all other output entries as undefined?

Comment: ^the above does not work when run, but I don't know how to write it otherwise and documentation does not explain.

Answer (score 2):

I believe below expression performs vectorized operations and avoid the use of  loops/lambda functions

```
np.sqrt(((input1>0) & 1)*input1) + np.sqrt(((input2>0) & 1)*input2)
```

Comment: I'm a student unfamiliar with industry. Is use of lambdas like the way I used them generally considered bad practice then?

Comment: Not a bad practice I would say. But it is not vectorized operation either. When you don't have long arrays, or in other non-numpy cases, this should not be a bad thing. In fact it's pythonic!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [121]: x = np.array([1, 10, 21, -1.])                                                
In [122]: y = 20-x                                                                      
In [123]: np.sqrt(x)                                                                    
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[123]: array([1.        , 3.16227766, 4.58257569,        nan])
```

There are several ways of dealing with 'out-of-range' values.

@Sam's approach is to tweak the inputs so they are valid

```
In [129]: ((x>0) & 1)*x                                                                 
Out[129]: array([ 1., 10., 21., -0.])
```

Another is to use masking to limit the values calculate.

Your function skips the `sqrt` is either input is negative; conversely it doe sthe calc where both are valid.  That's different from testing each separately.

```
In [124]: mask = (x>=0) & (y>=0)                                                        
In [125]: mask                                                                          
Out[125]: array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

We can use the mask thus:

```
In [126]: res = np.zeros_like(x)                                                        
In [127]: res[mask] = np.sqrt(x[mask]) + np.sqrt(y[mask])                               
In [128]: res                                                                           
Out[128]: array([5.35889894, 6.32455532, 0.        , 0.        ])
```

In my comments I suggested using the `where` parameter of `np.sqrt`.  It does, though, need an `out` parameter as well.

```
In [130]: np.sqrt(x, where=mask, out=np.zeros_like(x)) +
          np.sqrt(y, where=mask, out=np.zeros_like(x))                                                                   
Out[130]: array([5.35889894, 6.32455532, 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Alternatively if we are are happy with the `nan` in `Out[123]` we can just suppress the RuntimeWarning.