# How to create numpy array mask/masked array with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know that in Numpy you can mask an array based on a condition. For example, if I want a masked array for all values greater than 0.

```
arr[arr>0]
```

But I want to have two conditions for the mask. Intuitively, this would look like:

```
arr[arr>0 and arr<1]
```

but the compiler pops an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know I can use a for loop to solve this:

```
masked=np.array([i if(i>0 and i<1) for i in mask])
```

but is there a more elegant solution using something that's built-in for Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
arr[(arr > 0) & (arr < 1)]
```

Comment: thanks, I should have tried that. Is there an explanation as to why "and" doesn't work?

Comment: "and" expects to produce a scalar True/False.  You want elementwise logic.

Comment: Interesting, now that you mentioned it I found a page that explains this in a similar scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632033/how-to-perform-element-wise-boolean-operations-on-numpy-arrays.

Comment: `and` is a Python expression, more like a `if/else` clause than an operator.  `True and 1` returns `1`, more like `1 if True else False`. (except it short circuits)